# Is there a use case where Error is manually thrown?

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

I know it's a very noob question.

I have been going through blogs and articles trying to understand why and where Errors are used in Java, but no luck. In practice, I have never seen Errors being used and given that an Error occurs in an Abnormal condition.

Are these just for the internal libraries to use? Can it be manually thrown in a program? May be, we're not supposed to do it, but can we?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* throw them if you want. This is legal java code and runs fine:

```
class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    throw new Error();
  }
}
```

Just like runtime exceptions you don't need to declare that you do so (imagine you had written `throw new IOException();`, then it would not compile unless you turn that into `…main(String[] args) throws IOException`. RuntimeExceptions and Errors do not require being explicitly listed, however.

There is a *ton* of code out there that catches all exceptions. These are usually 'entrypoint controllers' - things that start applications. Java itself starts your main (and will catch anything main throws, and turn that into a nice print on the command line), but web servers and app servers and plugin runners all do similar things: A web server will receive an HTTP request, figure out which handler code is supposed to be invoked to deal with it, (someone wrote the web framework - but you wrote that handler), and will then catch any and all exceptions that fall out of that handler, to then serve up a 500 error and log a bunch of info about this event. Your `public void doGet()` or whatnot that you have to in your web handler is an *entry point*, and the point where the webframework invokes it, is called an *entrypoint controller*.

Most entrypoint controllers have a legitimate:

```
try {
    invokeEntryPoint();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // deal with it...
    // web frameworks would log the request, for example.
}
```

Many controllers **do not** catch error, and that is the pragmatic primary difference between a runtimeexception and an error: RuntimeExceptions and Errors do not need to be stated in `throws` clauses, but RuntimeExceptions are routinely caught, especially by entrypoint controllers, whereas errors often are not, and thus they result in a more thorough unwinding of the stack: It 'shuts down' deeper into the process. With a web server it may take down the entire webserver. This can be a good idea, for example, if a JVM invariant is broken because of disk corruption of the VM, or the system is out of memory, that can be a better option than just catching the error, logging (that logging itself could then be impossible due to memory issues), and continuing. Let the OS watchdog reboot the server automatically.

That's the pragmatic difference.

So, when should you throw an `Error`? Very rarely, but it is warranted if you have detected a violation of fundamental assumptions about your app, i.e. a bug or a misconfiguration (vs. an event that can reasonably occur during normal operation, such as an image file that was uploaded by a user that isn't valid). A common occurence of this is if you use `YourClass.class.getResource("states.txt")` to retrieve some data file that is as much a part of your application as your class files are: If that is missing, well, then your installation is corrupt, and the drastic nature of `Error` is quite warranted:

```
try (InputStream in = AbichandanisApp.class.getResource("splash_screen.png")) {
    if (in == null) throw new Error("Resource missing: splash_screen.png");
    renderSplashScreen(new Image(in));
}
```

That's an example of appropriate use of throwing `Error`.

Comment: Got it! Errors basically allow you to deviate the execution from something you never want to happen! Please correct me if I'm wrong...
Also, broken JVM is also a good reason why entrypoint controllers shouldn't catch an error.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer... :)

Comment: Well, throwables of any stripe can be used to 'deviate from normal execution', but, yes, Errors in particular are appropriate for situations that ought to be impossible, but if they do occur, you want as much stuff to shut down in its wake as is feasible - by definition, then, something you really don't want to ever happen. Such is the life of failsafe systems :)

Answer (score 0):

Of cause you could (the constructor is public).

And you should, if a *"serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch"* ocures in your code.

See:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html

Comment: Can you please provide an example where this would be required? bcz I understand an Error will be thrown only when absolutely required.

Comment: @Abichandani Maybe if you build a library that depends on the system to not be tampered with you could throw a `SystemHasBeenTamperedWithError`.

Comment: Makes sense! Again, helps to take care of a scenario that no one wants to happen, which I understand is the sole purpose of making errors public. Correct me if I'm wrong!